# Pyspark custom accumulators

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, accumulator

I was trying to run this program as an example of custom accumulators in pyspark. I am getting the error 'int is not iterable'. I cannot resolve this. Can someone please help me with this.

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import AccumulatorParam, SparkContext
sc = SparkContext('local','local')

rdd = sc.parallelize(xrange(10))

class SAP(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, initialValue):
        s=set()
        s.add(initialValue)
        return s
    def addInPlace(self, v1, v2):

        return v1.union(v2)



ids_seen = sc.accumulator(0, SAP())
def inc(x):
    global ids_seen
    ids_seen += x
    return x

rdd.foreach(inc)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of types `addInPlace` is `(R, R) => R` and `zero` is `(R) => R`.

The initial value should be of the same type as the type you expect in the accumulator so you have to initialize `Accumulator` with `set`:

```
ids_seen = sc.accumulator(set(), SAP())
```

or

```
ids_seen = sc.accumulator({0}, SAP())
```

and `zero` should be:

```
def zero(self, initialValue):
    return initialValue.copy()
```

Finally `inc` should add a `set`:

```
def inc(x):
    global ids_seen
    ids_seen += {x}
    return x
```

Comment: After hours of searching how to get a set type accumulator to work, your answer finally solved my issue. Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!